# Quarkus returning empty body response for UNAUTHORIZE

Tags: jwt, quarkus, smallrye

Currently I'm developing a REST API in quarkus that makes use of this two dependencies

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

As you can see, I'm expecting to receive a JWT token which identifies the requester. The problem appears when trying to customize the UNAUTHORIZE error response, currently I'm receiving one without any body but I'd like to introduce a JSON structure giving more details of the kin of error.

I've read this documentation about [HttpAuthenticationMechanism](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#httpauthenticationmechanism-customization)
but I'm not sure how to proceed here. Can someone lend me a hand with this problem? Is there any documentation that I'm missing or concept I should be accustom to?

To make this post clearer, I have code that interferes with the AuthenticationMechanism quarkus exposes and I'm using the out-of-the-box solution from smallrye-jwt dependency but this dependency returns UNAUTHORIZE messages with empty body and I want to return a simple JSON structure giving more details about the error Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters in the same situation as I was what I wanted to do is send back a tailored error message and ended up with the following code approach.

```
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
@ApplicationScoped
@JBossLog
public class AuthMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

  private static final String PARSING_JWT_ERROR = "Authentication failed! Error message \"{0}\"";
  private static final String UNKNOWN_ERROR = "Unknown error while validating toke. "
      + "Message from the exception \"{0}\"";

  @Inject
  JWTAuthMechanism delegate;

  @Override
  public Uni<SecurityIdentity> authenticate(RoutingContext context,
      IdentityProviderManager identityProviderManager) {
    context.data().put(QuarkusHttpUser.AUTH_FAILURE_HANDLER, customAuthErrorHandler());
    return delegate.authenticate(context, identityProviderManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Uni<ChallengeData> getChallenge(RoutingContext context) {
    return delegate.getChallenge(context);
  }

  @Override
  public Uni<Boolean> sendChallenge(RoutingContext context) {
    return delegate.sendChallenge(context);
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Class<? extends AuthenticationRequest>> getCredentialTypes() {
    return delegate.getCredentialTypes();
  }

  /**
   * <p>
   *   We overwrite the default error handler implemented by our quarkus dependencies with the
   *   sole purpose of tailor an error dto with extra information about the problem.
   * </p>
   * */
  private BiConsumer<RoutingContext, Throwable> customAuthErrorHandler() {
    return (context, throwable) -> {
      throwable = extractRootCause(throwable);
      if (throwable instanceof AuthenticationFailedException) {
        processFailedAuthentication((AuthenticationFailedException)throwable, context);
      } else {
        log.errorv(UNKNOWN_ERROR, throwable.getMessage());
        String bodyResponse = ErrorDtoGenerator.generateErrorDto(
            HttpResponseStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.reasonPhrase(),
            "Your token is not valid", "", Severity.ERROR.name());
        context.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.code())
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(bodyResponse.length()))
            .end(bodyResponse);
      }
    };
  }

  /**
   * <p>
   *   It will handle all possible authentication errors regarding the JWT validation.
   * </p>
   * */
  private void processFailedAuthentication(AuthenticationFailedException authenticationError,
      RoutingContext context) {
    context.response()
        .setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.code())
        .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    if (authenticationError.getCause() != null
        && authenticationError.getCause() instanceof ParseException) {
      log.errorv(PARSING_JWT_ERROR, authenticationError.getCause().getCause().getMessage());
      String errorBody = ErrorDtoGenerator.generateErrorDto(
          HttpResponseStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.reasonPhrase(),
          authenticationError.getCause().getMessage(),
          "", Severity.ERROR.name()
      );
      context.response()
          .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(errorBody.length()))
          .write(errorBody);
    }
    context.response().end();
  }

  private Throwable extractRootCause(Throwable throwable) {
    while ((throwable instanceof CompletionException && throwable.getCause() != null)
        || (throwable instanceof CompositeException)) {
      if (throwable instanceof CompositeException) {
        throwable = ((CompositeException) throwable).getCauses().get(0);
      } else {
        throwable = throwable.getCause();
      }
    }
    return throwable;
  }
}
```